# Speed up bash script while loop

Tags: bash, awk, while-loop, hexdump

This script redirects the output of a hexdump to a text file and then loops through it printing out rows. There are exactly 374371 rows of data in the file that look like this:

```
1a 03 1a 03 4a 03 57 03
4b 03 44 03 1e 03 09 04
10 03 19 03 40 03 ae 03
1e 03 26 03 33 03 ad 03
10 03 84 03 43 03 62 03
```

Here is the script:

```
if [ ! -d ./temp ]; then
  mkdir ./temp
  mount -t tmpfs -o size=128m tmpfs ./temp

  if [[ -s ./temp/samples.txt || ! -f ./temp/samples.txt ]]; then
    hexdump -e '8/1 "%02x " "\n"' samples.bin > ./temp/samples.txt
    echo "              ch0    ch1    ch2    ch3"
    x=0
    while read line;do
      echo "Sample "$x":        "$(echo $line | awk '{print "0x"$1$2"  0x"$3$4"  0x"$5$6"  0x"$7$8}')
      x=$((x+1))
    done<./temp/samples.txt
  fi
  umount ./temp
  rm -Rf ./temp
fi
```

The output looks like:

```
                ch0    ch1    ch2    ch3
Sample 0:       0x1a03 0x1a03 0x4a03 0x5703
Sample 1:       0x4b03 0x4403 0x1e03 0x0904
Sample 2:       0x1003 0x1903 0x4003 0xae03
Sample 3:       0x1e03 0x2603 0x3303 0xad03
Sample 4:       0x1003 0x8403 0x4303 0x6203
Sample 5:       0xe003 0x1603 0x3403 0xc403
Sample 6:       0xf802 0x3b03 0x5303 0x6103
Sample 7:       0x1003 0x1503 0x4203 0x5803
Sample 8:       0x2303 0x1f03 0x5703 0x6203
Sample 9:       0x1703 0x7303 0x3103 0x3303
Sample 10:      0x1403 0xff02 0x3003 0x5103
Sample 11:      0x5f03 0x4203 0x4703 0x7e03
Sample 12:      0xba03 0x2603 0x3503 0xa003
```

Even with tmpfs, the script doesn't run any faster than just reading from disk. Is there a way to make this script run any faster?

Comment: Just have `awk` process the file. It will run so fast you'll think it is broken.  Use the awk std internal variable `NR` to print the current 'Number(of)Record'. Good luck.

Comment: In each iteration of the loop, you create a pipe, involving the creation of two child-processes. This is not free. With such a huge file, I would ensure that no subprocess at all is created in the loop body, in particular since you don't need awk just for reformatting the input. You can equally well read the pieces of the line into a bash array, and process this array by bash internal commands only. This will already make your program much faster. If it still takes too long, switch from bash to, i.e., awk or Ruby or Perl.

Comment: @puppet_master : run whatever `awk` solution you have on hand with `mawk-2` : guarantee you minimum 20-25% speed up, all else being equal.

Comment: Thanks @RARE kpop Manifesto, even its name sounds blistering fast. I'll give it a go.

Comment: @RARE kpop Manifesto, OMG, the tshiono's awk script with mawk ran through the entire hexdump in 4 seconds. Awesome thanks. The original script with awk took 13.3 seconds, that's more than 3x faster.

Comment: @puppet_master : u ran it with `mawk-1` or `mawk-2` ? if u think `mawk-1` is fast, you'll be shocked when u encounter `mawk-2`

Comment: Thank you @RARE kpop Manifesto, I'll look for it. My Ubuntu Kinetic Kudu 22.04 droplet already had mawk installed, and I looked around and couldn't find mawk-2. Can you provide me with a link?

Comment: @puppet_master : technically it's a beta, so use it with care : https://github.com/mikebrennan000/mawk-2. but if u ask me - despite being labeled "beta" , it has fewer problems than any other `awk` i've ever encountered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to speed-up the script, consider to use `awk` instead of `bash` as Shellter comments. Then would you please try:

```
hexdump -v -e '8/1 "%02x " "\n"' samples.bin | awk '
    BEGIN {
        print "                ch0    ch1    ch2    ch3"        # print the header line
    }
    {
        printf("Sample %d:", NR - 1)                            # print the sample number
        printf(substr("        ", 1, 8 - length(NR - 1)))       # adjust the length of the spaces
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i+=2) {                            # print every two nibbles
            j = i + 1
            printf("0x%s%s%s", $i, $j, j == NF ? ORS : OFS)
        }
    }
'
```

Output with the provided file:

```
                ch0    ch1    ch2    ch3
Sample 0:       0x1a03 0x1a03 0x4a03 0x5703
Sample 1:       0x4b03 0x4403 0x1e03 0x0904
Sample 2:       0x1003 0x1903 0x4003 0xae03
Sample 3:       0x1e03 0x2603 0x3303 0xad03
Sample 4:       0x1003 0x8403 0x4303 0x6203
```

The `-v` option tells `hexdump` to display all input data instead of summarizing with an asterisk meaning `same as the line above`.

Comment: Hi @tshiono, good job and thank you for the work you've done here, and all on your own dime. Your solution only took 13.13 seconds on a digital ocean droplet, (so your mileage may vary), with 2 CPUs and 4GB mem. I'll test the other offered solutions and see who's is quickest. Thanks again.

Comment: Updated the answer without using the temporary file to speed up. BR.

Comment: Thank you for updating your solution @tshiono, it works perfectly, and it's very elegant. I vote yours to be the best solution because you made it work without samples.txt, and because you started the first sample at 0. I'm sure with slight modifications, ravinderSingh13's solution would be just as good.

Comment: Hi @tshiono, we're back in business thanks to you, my son, and several people on stack here, thanks for all your help. Here's a sample of the output: https://www.usreliance.com/stack-reply.html

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Reading Input_file 2 times but first time it reads only very first line to get TOTAL number of fields and moves to the 2nd time its run.

```bash
awk '
BEGIN{
  print"\tch0    ch1    ch2    ch3"
}
FNR==NR{
  totalCount=NF
  nextfile
}
RT{
  gsub(/^[[:space:]]|\n+$/,"",RT)
  sub(/ /,"",RT)
  val=(val?val OFS:"") "0x1" RT
  if(++count%(totalCount/2)==0){
     print "Sample "++count2":\t"val
     val=count=""
  }
}
' Input_file RS="(^|\n| )[[:alnum:]]{2} [[:alnum:]]{2}" Input_file | 
column  -t -s $'\t'
```

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13, your code ran just a shade slower (at 14.08 seconds) than tshiono's, probably because it has to make 2 passes through samples.txt. Excellent solution though, and thanks.

Comment: @puppet_master, one more thing if your number of Fields fixed in lines then we can avoid the first pass of file and keep it only one. This 2 pass solution was given for making it a generic solution just want to mention it here.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13, I need to learn awk like you and tshiono, I will not always be in a situation where I have time to wait for an answer, like when I'm putting out a fire at work. Awk to me seems like a nice quick and dirty solution that's faster than using Python if you know it really well.

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13, thank you for all of your help and guidance, my son and I are coming down the home stretch. Here's a sample of our progress. https://www.usreliance.com/stack-reply.html

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible with `sed`. I found `sed` in general to be faster than `awk`.

```
cat -n | sed 's/\s*\([0-9]*\)\s*\([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\)/Sample \1:\t0x\2\3 0x\4\5 0x\6\7 0x\8\9/'
```

Comment: Hi @Ljm Dullaart, your solution was the second fastest coming in at 13.82 seconds just behind tshiono's script. Now this is on a droplet which probably shares resources with other VPCs, so it could be an unfair comparison due to this fact. But I love the efficiency of using a one liner like yours. Thanks.

Comment: This reads from the hexdump @Ljm Dullaart: `hexdump -e '8/1 "%02x " "\n"' samples.bin | cat -n | sed 's/\s*\([0-9]*\)\s*\([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\)/Sample \1:\t0x\2\3 0x\4\5 0x\6\7 0x\8\9/'`, but the sample rows start with one instead of zero. Is there any way to fix this?